self.ctx.$scope.$apply is not a function
I am creating a custom widget on thingboard pe to call an api endpoint and display results in table format. I have been running into this error - self.ctx.$scope.$apply is not a function and for the life of me cant seem to find a solution. Looking at the browser console, I know the api request is done and status 200 is received along with results in JSON. Anyone know how i can solve this. here is my code -
`
self.onInit = function() {
    self.ctx.$scope.fetchData = function() {
        const url = 'https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        const username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
        const password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 

        const headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${username}:${password}`),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        fetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers: headers })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                self.ctx.$scope.$apply(function() {
                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                        self.ctx.$scope.data = data;
                    } else {
                        self.ctx.$scope.data = null;
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
                self.ctx.$scope.$apply(function() {
                    self.ctx.$scope.data = null;
                });
            });
    };

    self.ctx.$scope.fetchData();
};

Tried using $timeout instead no dice

Maybe you alter your $scope variable?

Hi @Justinas. In what sense?

self.ctx.$scope = {}. Add break point on $apply line and inspect self.ctx.$scope

sorry can you showme i do not have much experience with js

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript

Thingsboard's $scope is a custom structure and it doesn't have Angular's $apply function.
So simply do the following
...
.then(data => {
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        self.ctx.$scope.data = data;
    } else {
        self.ctx.$scope.data = null;
    }
})
...


What do you have self set as?  it may help to do a console.log here:
        .then(data => {
            console.log(self, 'self'); // added this line to debug (if you don't see `$scope.$apply` then there's your answer)
            self.ctx.$scope.$apply(function() {


console.log(self, 'self'); returns  _system_customWidget 'self' if I log data i see the correct json api response. Do you have any suggestions on how i can fix it?

Yeah I think you can assume the data is coming back correctly for now.  The problem is this custom $scope.$apply.  It's never stated anywhere but this is an angularJS application?  We may need to see the "setup" before this method to determine what self.ctx is... if anything.  Did you inherit this codebase?
console.logging self should have shown some sort of object like {ctx: {$scope: $apply: something}}, otherwise that doesn't exist.

this is probably related to thingsboard widgets not angularJS.
If so, the options available for self are what's listed in IDynamicWidgetComponent.  What are you trying to do with the $scope.$apply?
